# Formula to Compare Values from Changing List

Tags: excel, formula

Hi there so I have a list of items as follows - where in the Sample 1 column, Blue (I guess parent) is followed by Red (child) and the account numbers in Acct 1 should all be the same as the preceding Blue in that section (until the next Blue is listed with another acct number).

In the example below the 3th and 7th records need to be tagged/identified.  Is there any easy way to do this with a formula?  I have about 100K line items with this information.  Thank you much!!

```
Sample 1    Acct
Blue        1234
Red         1234
Red         2458
Red         1234
Blue        5768
Red         5768
Red         2589
Red         5768
```

Comment: Is the parent always literally "Blue" and the children "Red", or can they vary? What version of Excel do you use?

Comment: Can vary and Office 365

Comment: And to clarify only two options are given under Sample 1 column, so can be yellow or green or In or Out, etc...

Comment: I think it's do-able, perhaps with xlookup and conditional formatting, but would have to think about how to handle some special cases like (a) no children (b) one child (c) two children, both different... Unfortunately not going to be around much till later tomorrow, but will have a look at it when free.

Answer (score 1):

This is my suggestion. It looks before and after the current cell in column A to find the first cells which don't match in both directions, then takes the range between these cells. If there are at least as many cells in column B that don't match the current acct as do match it in the current range, then it is assumed that the current cell is a mistake (in the case where there are two children and their acct's don't match, then they would both be flagged).

```
=LET(range,INDEX(A:A,XMATCH(TRUE,A$1:A2<>A2,0,-1)+ROW(A$1)):INDEX(B:B,XMATCH(TRUE,A2:A$10<>A2,0)+ROW()-2),
sample,INDEX(range,0,1),
acct,INDEX(range,0,2),
equal,COUNTIF(acct,B2),
unequal,COUNTIF(acct,"<>"&B2),
unequal>=equal)
```

Unfortunately this formula doesn't work in conditional formatting, so it would mean putting it in a separate column, dragging it down and filtering on the TRUE values.

[image]

I will have a look at modifying the formula to work in CF.

This works in CF but is slow - will need to remove full-column  ranges.

```
=LET(start,XMATCH(TRUE,A$1:A2<>A2,0,-1)+ROW(A$1),end,XMATCH(TRUE,A2:A$10<>A2,0)+ROW()-2,
sample,FILTER(A:A,(ROW(A:A)>=start)*(ROW(A:A)<=end)),
acct,FILTER(B:B,(ROW(B:B)>=start)*(ROW(B:B)<=end)),
equal,SUM(--(acct=B2)),
unequal,SUM(--(acct<>B2)),
unequal>=equal)
```

This I think is OK

```
=LET(start,XMATCH(TRUE,A$1:A2<>A2,0,-1)+1,end,XMATCH(TRUE,A2:A$10<>A2,0)+ROW()-ROW(A$1)-1,
seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A$1:A$10)),
sample,FILTER(A$1:A$10,(seq>=start)*(seq<=end)),
acct,FILTER(B$1:B$10,(seq>=start)*(seq<=end)),
equal,SUM(--(acct=B2)),
unequal,SUM(--(acct<>B2)),
unequal>=equal)
```

[image]

---

If I have misunderstood the whole thing and the parent and child is literally labelled as Blue or Red for the whole of sample 1, then you would just need this in conditional formatting:

```
=AND(A2="Red",B2<>XLOOKUP("Blue",A$1:A2,B$1:B2,,0,-1))
```

and this to mark each block with an increasing count

```
=IF(A2="Blue",C1+1,C1)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness... ok will try this out.  I was further thinking and was wondering, what if instead (to simplify a bit), is there a formula where after each change in "Red" it adds a numerical value.  For example in my sample data "Sample " column, the first Blue would be 1 and all the "Red's" following that Blue would also be labeled as 1 until the next Blue shows up and then that one along with all the Red's below it would be labeled 2, and so on...  Is there a formula for that?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It's late here so will have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Great - thank you!  I tried replicating the formula but getting a n/a error message... wonder what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Don't know! Can you post a screenshot? In answer to your other question, try this, just a simple pull-down formula that increases for each alternate change in the sample column: =QUOTIENT(SUM(--(A$1:A1<>A$2:A2))-1,2)+1 starting in A2

Comment: Maybe a better way, since each parent should have something not a parent before and after it, would be =IF(AND(A2<>A1,A2<>A3),O1+1,O1) [I happen to be working in column O].  But this wouldn't work in the case where there is only one child.

Comment: BTW it has occurred to me that if you didn't mind the lines before and after the discrepancy to be highlighted as well as the actual discrepancy, the formula could be massively simplified.

Comment: Sorry, starting to spam you here. Do you have an estimate of how many cases there are with only one child? Is it rare or common? I'm assuming all through this that you don't have a handy list of what the parents and /or children in the first column are actually labelled as?

Comment: Hi Tom - there are many instances where there is only one child per parent relationship.  Let me try your other formulas and see if that simplies it.  As for the screenshots, I've tried to post an image, but since I'm new to the forum it doesn't allow me.

Comment: OK, thanks. As far as I know, you can still upload an image to IMGUR and post a link to it. It would be very interesting to see some of your actual data, but I guess it's confidential.

Comment: With hindsight I think maybe I've over-complicated this and in your comment earlier you meant that _only_ Blue and red alternated in Sample1 all the way down...I was thinking it might change to green and yellow or something... that's the trouble with small examples, you don't always get the big picture (and if I'm honest my brain wasn't working too well yesterday).

Comment: I feel like your simplified formula above: =AND(A2="Red",B2<>XLOOKUP("Blue",A$1:A2,B$1:B2,,0,-1)) should work except that I'm still getting an #N/A error message and cannot see why.  I copied the formula exactly as it appears, data is also in the same columns (A & B) but the formula returns an error.  And, yes, unfortunately the data I'm working with is confidential, hence the reason I did not post the actual data.

Comment: That's really annoying! I will add a screenshot of my formula working so you can compare it with your result. Column C isn't necessary, but have added it because you suggested it might be useful. C1 has to be empty or zero.

Comment: Try Formula | Evaluate Formula is the only other thing I can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

It's more efficient to do this with a spill formula that calculates the entire column at once.

I took a screenshot to explain the formula, but all that is required is one formula in cell `C2`.
[image: Screenshot of formula]

Here is the unoptimised formula to create a spill column. It creates a bunch of arrays the height of your data and does operations on them to find the incorrect accounts.

```
=LET(
    MultiLevelID, A2:A9,
    Account, B2:B9,
    sParent, "Blue",
    sChild, "Red",

    ArrayIndex, SEQUENCE(ROWS(MultiLevelID)),
    ArrayBoolParent, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(MultiLevelID, sParent)),
    ArrayParentIndex, IF(ArrayBoolParent=TRUE,ArrayIndex,0),
    ArrayAllIndexes, XLOOKUP(ArrayIndex,ArrayParentIndex,ArrayParentIndex,,-1),
    ArrayCorrectAccount, XLOOKUP(ArrayAllIndexes,ArrayIndex,Account),
    ArrayBoolIncorrect, IF(Account=ArrayCorrectAccount,FALSE,TRUE),

    ArrayBoolIncorrect
)
```

`ArrayIndex` is an array that starts at 1 and keeps counting up for the height of your data. `SEQUENCE` is for this exact purpose. It will be used as a 'row' reference. Note, these are rows relative to the selected data, not actual excel row numbers.

`ArrayBoolParent` is an array with `TRUE` for every parent and `FALSE` for every child. `XMATCH` is searching for the parent name, and returns the index if it is found and and error if not. `ISNUMBER` makes the output `TRUE` if found and `FALSE` if not. Using `XMATCH` lets you search for multiple criteria. For example, if "Light Blue" was also a parent, you could set `sParent` equal to `{"Blue", "Light Blue"}.

`ArrayParentIndex` is an array with the index for every parent and 0 for every child. I'm using an interesting application of `IF` to do this. When `IF` is given an array as the condition, it does an `IF` statement for each item in the array. When a return value is also an array, it returns the item relating to the condition instead of the whole array.

`ArrayCorrectedIndexes` is an array with all children's indexes pointing to their parent. Similar to `IF`, using an array with `XLOOKUP` performs the search on all items in the array separately. I'm also using one of the advanced functions of `XLOOKUP`, which says if a value isn't found, return the next largest value. This means when I search for index 2, it finds nothing and returns the next smallest value, 1.

`ArrayCorrectAccount` is an array with the parent account automatically assigned to each child. I used `XLOOKUP` for clarity, but you could also use `INDEX(Account,ArrayCorrectedIndexes)`.

`ArrayBoolIncorrect` is an array that returns `FALSE` if the account is correct, and `TRUE` if not.

If you are looking for a summary of what needs to be fixed, only return the incorrect indexes:

```
FirstRow, MIN(ROW(MultiLevelID)) - 1,
FILTER(ArrayIndex + FirstRow, ArrayBoolIncorrect <> FALSE)
```

Lastly, if you want a dynamic table to summarize the errors, use this:

```
=LET(
    MultiLevelID, A2:A9,
    Account, B2:B9,
    sParent, "Blue",
    sChild, "Red",

    FirstRow, MIN(ROW(MultiLevelID)) - 1,
    ArrayIndex, SEQUENCE(ROWS(MultiLevelID)),
    ArrayBoolParent, ISNUMBER(XMATCH(MultiLevelID, sParent)),
    ArrayParentIndex, IF(ArrayBoolParent=TRUE,ArrayIndex,0),
    ArrayCorrectedIndexes, XLOOKUP(ArrayIndex,ArrayParentIndex,ArrayParentIndex,,-1),
    ArrayCorrectAccount, XLOOKUP(ArrayCorrectedIndexes,ArrayIndex,Account),
    ArrayBoolIncorrect, IF(Account=ArrayCorrectAccount,FALSE,TRUE),

    ArrayInccorrectIndexes, FILTER(ArrayIndex, ArrayBoolIncorrect <> FALSE),
    ArrayInccorrectRows, ArrayInccorrectIndexes + FirstRow,

    Categories, ArrayInccorrectIndexes,

    Body_Instance, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Categories)),
    Body_Parent,  INDEX(MultiLevelID,INDEX(ArrayCorrectedIndexes, Categories)),
    Body_Child,  INDEX(MultiLevelID, Categories),
    Body_IncorrectAcct, INDEX(Account, Categories),
    Body_CorrectAcct, INDEX(ArrayCorrectAccount, Categories),
    Body_IncorrectRows, ArrayInccorrectRows,

    Total_Rows, COUNT(Categories),

    Array_Seq, {1,2,3,4,5,6},
    Array_Header, CHOOSE( Array_Seq, "Instance",          "Row Location",            "Parent",           "Child",          "Correct Acct",         "Incorrect Acct",          ),
    Array_Body,  CHOOSE( Array_Seq,   Body_Instance,  Body_IncorrectRows, Body_Parent,    Body_Child,  Body_CorrectAcct, Body_IncorrectAcct, ),
    Array_Total,     CHOOSE( Array_Seq,  "",                                        "",                        "",                      "",                                 "Count",                         Total_Rows),

    Range1,Array_Header,
    Range2,Array_Body,
    Range3,Array_Total,
    Rows1,ROWS(Range1), Rows2,ROWS(Range2), Rows3,ROWS(Range3), Cols1,COLUMNS(Range1),
    RowIndex, SEQUENCE(Rows1 + Rows2 + Rows3), ColIndex,SEQUENCE(1, Cols1),
    RangeTable,IF(
        RowIndex<=Rows1,
        INDEX(Range1,RowIndex,ColIndex),
        IF(RowIndex<=Rows1+Rows2,
            INDEX(Range2,RowIndex-Rows1,ColIndex),
            INDEX(Range3,RowIndex-Rows1-Rows2,ColIndex)
    )),

    Return, RangeTable,
    Return
)
```